# python global variable with multiple files how thay work?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

how python's global variable work?
if I declare them where are they in the memory?

**z1.py**

```
a = [123]
```

**z2.py**

```
from z1 import a

print(a)
print(a)
```

**z3.py**

```
from z1 import a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(a)
    a[0] = 234
    import z2
```

**result**

```
[123]
[234]
[234]
```

this time, work very well what I expected. but if I don't use a list type the result different

**z1.py**

```
a = True
```

**z2.py**

```
from z1 import a

print(a)
print(a)
```

**z3.py**

```
from z1 import a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(a)
    a = False
    import z2
```

**result**

```
True
True
True
```

what's the different? I think using list type maybe put they're code in heap memory.
but when I use boolean also I think put they're code in main stack area so work well.
but not.

Comment: Booleans are a subclass of integers, which are immutable. Lists are mutable collections

Answer (score 1):

When you import `a`, you basically create a variable with a pointer to the value defined in z1. Basically, you are saying : '

> In z3, create a variable with name `a` pointing to the same address as `a` in z1.

In the list example, it works as intended because lists are mutable, so you can modify the value behind the pointer.

However, booleans are immutable so each value (True and False) has a pre-defined address in memory and you can't modify the value behind these addresses. So when you write `a = False`, you are saying :

> To the variable `a` which used to point to the address of `True`, assign a pointer pointing to the address of `False`

Thus, you did not modify any value in memory, only the local pointer in your z3 file. Then when you import z1 in z2, you are once again copying the pointer to `True`.

See [this](https://realpython.com/python-mutable-vs-immutable-types/#common-mutability-related-gotchas) for more info